# How to create checkboxes from a list

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to learn to code with Python. I'm trying to create checkbuttons from a list by using a for loop.  After the user checks the appropriate boxes, I'd like to end up with a subset of the original list containing only the values corresponding to checked boxes.  I've gotten the checkbuttons to show ok, but what do I need to do to get the values of the checkboxes into a list?  I've looked at several examples but I may not have understood correctly since I'm still learning all of this.  Thanks for the help.

```
category_data = ['Home', 'Auto', 'Groceries','Medical']

for category in category_data:
    l=Checkbutton(root, text= category,onvalue = True, offvalue= False)
    l.pack(anchor=W)
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to assign a `BooleanVar` to each `Checkbox` in order to get its status.  Then you need to use a `dict` to store those `BooleanVar` using category as the key.

Later you can go through the `dict` to create the required list of checked categories.

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

category_data = ['Home', 'Auto', 'Groceries', 'Medical']

cb_vars = {}  # dict to store the BooleanVar
for category in category_data:
    var = BooleanVar()
    l = Checkbutton(root, text=category, variable=var, onvalue=True, offvalue=False)
    l.pack(anchor=W)
    cb_vars[category] = var  # store the BooleanVar

def show_selected_categories():
    selected_category = [c for c in cb_vars if cb_vars[c].get()]
    print(selected_category)

Button(root, text="Check", command=show_selected_categories).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create a list, `category_values`, and append `tk.BooleanVar` objects to it that are used for the checkbuttons.

```py
category_data = ['Home', 'Auto', 'Groceries','Medical']
category_values = []

for category in category_data:
    category_values.append(BooleanVar())
    l=Checkbutton(root, text= category, variable=category_values[-1], onvalue = True, offvalue= False)
    l.pack(anchor=W)
```

and to get the value:

```py
category_values[<category number>].get()
```